# how to solve ValueError in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a image search engine application, I have the code in separate `.py` files and it's working fine. But I want to optimize it. When I use the function below, it's giving me a ValueError.

My code is like this(only relevant lines i have taken):

```
def example():
  i = 0
  resultlist_key = []
  result_list = list()
  a_list = list()
  b_list = list()
  a_list.append(feature_matrix_ip)# feature_matrix_ip contains features of the query image
  while i < 70:
      b_list.append(feature_matrix_db[i])# feature_matrix_db contains features of img. in DB
      dist = distance.euclidean(a_list,b_list[i])
      result_list.append(dist)
      resultlist_key = OrderedDict(sorted(enumerate(result_list),key=lambda x: x[0])).keys()
      i = i + 1 
      res_lst_srt = {'values': result_list,'keys':resultlist_key}
      res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'] = zip(*sorted(zip(res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'])))# sorting according to the least distance and the key will not change
      key = res_lst_srt['keys']
```

When I analyze, I didn't get any solutions for this. My error statement is:

```
%run "D:/6th sem/Major project/Code/frame.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.0.3.1262.win-x86\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "D:\6th sem\Major project\Code\frame.py", line 323, in matching_image
res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'] = zip(*sorted(zip(res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'])))

ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I have no idea whether this error comes from the naming problem or not. It will work correctly when the code is outside the function, but I want the code to be inside the function, so that the program is optimized.

Any suggestions on solving this error?

Comment: If you do `print zip(*sorted(zip(res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'])))` just before the line having the error, what's the output?

Comment: @Kevin When I tried to print ti, then I got this result `{'keys': [], 'values': []}`, but when I tried to print the sane outside the function, I'm getting the key and values properly.

Comment: Are you sure that's the result of `print zip(...`? Because that's a dict, and zip only ever returns a list.

Comment: @Kevin yes, I'm sure about the result. Do you have any suggestion, so that the same code works inside the function also?

Comment: I'm really confused about how that's possible. Please provide a [short, self-contained, runnable example](http://www.sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem. There's not much more I can do unless I can see the error occur on my own machine.

Comment: I'm with @Kevin... Your `print` statement shows a dictionary, which `zip` never returns... Aren't you missing a `[` somewhere? Anyway, let's try to narrow the issue: Right over the line that gives you the error add a line `print "i: %s, rest_lst_srt: %s" % (i, rest_lst_srt)` and add the output to your question (that'll show in what iteration is failing and why). Also, it looks to me that you're trying to do what's described on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2733056/289011 If that's the case, your code can be probably reduced. Are you **sure** you need an `OrderedDict` to sort the `result_list`?

Comment: @BorrajaX  I'm using `OrderedDict` because it gives me the index as the image are inputted. So that the sorting and retrieving of the image will be easy for me. I had tried without `OrderedDict`, then the image sequence will change, and the result in an unrelated image :(

Comment: @user3483746, Right... Is just that is making the code very difficult to follow *for me* **:-D** Anyway... how about the other part of the comment? (the `print "i %s...` thingy?)

Comment: Yeah, where is the magic number 70 coming from? It could be that you're iterating too high?

Answer (score 0):

So, my guess is that this part:

`zip(*sorted(zip(res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'])))`

is returning an empty list to any of the `zip`s:

```
>>> foo, bar = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Now, if you want to populate `res_lst_srt` (as it seems I understood from your question), why don't you make it simpler?

```
>>> values=[1,2,3]
>>> keys=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> my_dict
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

(`values` here would be `res_lst_srt['values']`, `keys` would be `res_lst_srt['keys']` and `my_dict` would be `res_lst_srt`. No? Shouldn't that work?

Comment: Actually this line of code `zip(*sorted(zip(res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'])))` will sort the values in the ascending order irrespective of its key. If I do as you suggested, then I may not get the required image.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be found by looking at this simple case.

```
>>> a, b = tuple() # or you could write a, b = []

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#319>", line 1, in <module>
    a, b = tuple()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
>>>
```

The length of values on one side of the equals operator must match the other.

So its clear that the values returned by..

```
zip(*sorted(zip(res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'])))
```

..end up returning an empty list/tuple. Which is causing you grief.

Comment: yes, but I'm confused, as when the code is outside the function I will get the values, but when the same code inside the function, its giving me an empty lists.