# How do I solve this valueerror while installing pyautogui?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, jpeg

Please note that this query is not the same as:
[How to install PyAutoGUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939986/how-to-install-pyautogui)
or
[how to solve ValueError in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067639/how-to-solve-valueerror-in-python)

I am working on an Ubuntu machine. I used the command **pip install pyautogui**. Everything goes well until I get this on the terminal:

```
File "/tmp/pip-build-gXkSEJ/Pillow/setup.py", line 516, in build_extensions

(f, f))

ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gXkSEJ/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d_80Eq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gXkSEJ/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpHnGt1t
```

Comment: what about with `easy_install pyautogui`?

Comment: Message shows that problem is with `Pillow` and `JPEG`. Maybe find answer for this problem. Probably you have to use `apt-get` to install some jpeg library (C/C++)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`

Answer (score 0):

You must first run `pip install pillow`. However, as of 0.9.34 of PyAutoGUI, you do not need to do this anymore and can just try running `pip install pyautogui`