# Filling in 2 lists in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 lists:

```
list_a = [2016, 2025, 2050, 2075]
list_b = [34.5, 43.5, 65.8, 88.2]
```

I want to extend list_a so that all values between 2016 to 2075 are filled i.e. 2016, 2017, ... 2074, 2075. list_b values should all be linearly interpolated, so that lengths of list_a and list_b are the same.

Really not sure how to do this apart from maybe apply a for loop.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: what do you mean that the values of list_b are linearly interpolated? what is the logic?

Comment: The first thing I ask myself when doing this is how would I do it by hand.  Then I carefully describe what I did and turn it into code.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that your lists are sorted?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732994/python-sort-a-list-and-change-another-one-consequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has `numpy` tag, I assume that it's supposed to use numpy.

Also, I assume that `list_a` is sorted.

`numpy.arange(list_a[0], list_a[-1])` gives numpy array `[2016, 2017, ...]`.

`numpy.interp(numpy.arange(list_a[0], list_a[-1]), list_a, list_b)` gives you linearly interpotaled function values `[34.5, 35.5, ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for a very naive interpolation

```
list_a_final = [i for i in range(list_a[0], list_a[-1] +1)]
list_b_final = [list_b[0] + (list_b[-1]-list_b[0])/(len(list_a_final) -1) * i for i in range(len(list_a_final))]
```

output

```
list_b_final = [34.5, 35.41016949152542, 36.320338983050846, 37.23050847457627, 38.140677966101
7, 39.05084745762712, 39.961016949152544, 40.87118644067797, 41.78135593220339,
42.69152542372881, 43.60169491525424, 44.511864406779665, 45.42203389830509, 46.
33220338983051, 47.242372881355934, 48.152542372881356, 49.06271186440678, 49.97
28813559322, 50.883050847457625, 51.79322033898305, 52.70338983050848, 53.613559
3220339, 54.52372881355932, 55.433898305084746, 56.344067796610176, 57.254237288
1356, 58.16440677966102, 59.074576271186444, 59.98474576271187, 60.8949152542372
9, 61.80508474576271, 62.715254237288136, 63.62542372881356, 64.53559322033898,
65.4457627118644, 66.35593220338984, 67.26610169491525, 68.17627118644069, 69.08
64406779661, 69.99661016949153, 70.90677966101696, 71.81694915254238, 72.7271186
440678, 73.63728813559322, 74.54745762711865, 75.45762711864407, 76.367796610169
49, 77.27796610169491, 78.18813559322035, 79.09830508474576, 80.0084745762712, 8
0.9186440677966, 81.82881355932204, 82.73898305084745, 83.64915254237289, 84.559
32203389831, 85.46949152542373, 86.37966101694916, 87.28983050847458, 88.2]
```

As you can see, the two middle values are missed slightly because the interpolation is done from the starting and ending values> If you need something more precise, look into curve fitting.

Answer (score -1):

The first part is easy:

list_aa = range(list_a[0],list_a[len(list_a)-1])

For the second part you need to interpolate and sample the same number of points as in the new list_aa, e.g. like this: numpy.interp(list_aa,list_a,list_b)